# Javascript Object Structure Without Key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate an object structure like so:

```
{nums: {500: 0, 600: 0}}
```

I have a function that loops and returns numbers as shown in object: 500 & 600. However,

No matter what I try to create an object structure like the above, it does not work.

This is what I have an array of object as follows :

```
 const scores = [ {score: 500}, {variant_id: 600} ]
```

How can I loop through the scores array of object and get a structure like:
Number 0 in this example as a value that will be applicable to all scores.

```
 {nums: {500: 0, 600: 0}}
```

What I have done is:

```
  let filteredScores = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            const element = scores[i];
            filteredScores.push(element);
  }
```

However, this does not lead to the desired results.

Any insights or input is much appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to make an object, why would you use array.push?

Comment: what is the source of the zero in the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of ideas using `reduce()` and `Object.values()`.

```js
const scores = [ {score: 500}, {variant_id: 600} ];

const result1 = scores.reduce((o, item) => {
    o.nums[Object.values(item)[0]] = 0
    return o;
}, { nums: {} });
console.log(result1);

// Basically the same thing, just more compact
const result2 = { nums: scores.reduce((o, item) => ({...o, [Object.values(item)[0]]: 0}), {})};

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` in conjunction with `Array#map`. (To get the first property value of an object, you can retrieve the first element of the array returned by `Object.values`.)

```js
const scores = [ {score: 500}, {variant_id: 600} ];
const res = {nums: Object.fromEntries(scores.map(x => [Object.values(x)[0], 0]))};
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var scores = [ {score: 500}, {variant_id: 600} ],
    result = scores.reduce( (r,o) => ( Object.keys(o).forEach(k => r.nums[o[k]] = 0)
                                     , r
                                     )
                          , {nums:{}}
                          );
console.log(result);
```